# Makefile no rule to make target index.html needed by all?

Tags: makefile

Need a fresh pair of eyes on this. Thanks in advance. Isn't the rule '%.html' ? I'm wanting to find all my wiki files and convert them with pandoc to html.

```
SOURCES = $(shell find $$wiki -name "*.wiki")
HTML=$(patsubst %.wiki,%.html,$(SOURCES))

all: $(HTML)

%.html: $(SOURCES)
    @echo -e "Converting wiki file $@ to html."
```

Comment: Well, it would help if you told us what the problem is that you're having.  What is the shell variable `$wiki` set to before this makefile runs?  The command `$(shell find $$wiki ...)` will run the shell command `find $wiki ...` and the shell will expand `$wiki` as a variable.

Comment: It's kind of weird that you use `%.html : $(SOURCES)` which says, each individual `.html` file depends on _all_ the source files, so if _any_ source file is changed than all the `.html` files are out of date.  Why don't you use `%.html : %.wiki`?

Comment: @MadScientist find all files that end with .wiki in the directory of $wiki and convert them to html files. I'm getting the error in the title. How would the makefile know what %.wiki is without using $(SOURCES) ?

Comment: I think there's some confusion about what a pattern rule is.  make knows what it wants to build because of the `all` rule, which has the `.html` files as prerequisites.  So make will try to figure out how to build each `.html` file, say `index.html`.  It will find that there's a pattern rule with a target of `%.html` which matches the file it wants to build, so then it tries to build the prerequisites of that.  If you list `$(SOURCES)` as the prerequisites, then ALL sources are prerequisites, so `index.html` will depend on every source file, not just the `index.wiki` file.

Comment: @MadScientist I see what you're saying. I agree that's a tricky situation. How would I go about fixing this? You're saying that all the html files or one html file depend on all the sources instead of having each individual one depending on one? So for example the correct way would be foo.html depends on foo.wiki... instead of foo.html depends on foo.wiki, bar.wiki ....etc.... Maybe putting a makefile function $(call somefunction) as the dependency?

Comment: This is exactly what pattern rules are designed for.  You simply put the pattern in the prerequisite as well, just as I said in my comment above.  E.g., write `%.html : %.wiki` and now `index.html` depends only on `index.wiki`, not on all the wiki files.

Comment: @MadScientist you're right, it's interesting how makefile knows what %.wiki is, it's a wild card of the target so if the target is foo.html the dependency becomes foo.wiki with ```%.wiki``` how you mentioned. Looks like the dependency is using the wild card on the target.

Comment: Not really.  You're making it too complicated: it's actually very simple.  Make starts with the TARGET IT WANTS TO BUILD, and works "backward" trying to build things, until it runs out of things to build.  Here you want to build `all`, and there's a target for that.  The target depends on `foo.html`, `index.html`, etc. so make tries to build each one of those.  There's no explicit rule so it looks through the pattern rules, matching each pattern `%.c`, `%.cpp`, ... it finds your `%.index` where `%` matches `foo`.  It then replaces `%` in the dependency list with `foo` and checks that.

Comment: @MadScientist Gotcha. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem** - It was finding other files in directories that had files with spaces.

**Solution** - Restricted the search with the find command.